# Federated users with WSO2 AM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm trying to use WSO2-AM with federated users. I've had success with authenticating federated users using the Implicit grant, but having a problem with the authorized code grant.

Specifically, when using

```
 <GrantTypeHandlerImplClass>org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.ExtendedAuthorizationCodeGrantHandler</GrantTypeHandlerImplClass>
```

I get an error

```
    TID: [-1234] [] [2018-05-27 22:48:18,476] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.issuers.RoleBasedScopesIssuer} -  Error when getting the tena
nt's UserStoreManager or when getting roles of user  
org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Invalid Domain Name
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.callSecure(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:173)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.getRoleListOfUser(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:2716)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.issuers.RoleBasedScopesIssuer.getScopes(RoleBasedScopesIssuer.java:131)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.ScopesIssuer.setScopes(ScopesIssuer.java:109)
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.keymgt.handlers.ExtendedAuthorizationCodeGrantHandler.validateScope(ExtendedAuthorizationCodeGrantHandler.
java:48)
```

because it doesn't like the 'FEDERATED' domain of the authenticated user when calling the relevant AbstractUserStoreManager method.

Has anyone come across this before or might know how to handle federated users in API Manager ?

P.S. If I instead use the Identity Server class

```
org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.AuthorizationCodeGrantHandler
```

it all works fine with federated users.

Comment: You may specify the WSO2AM version number. I had no problems with federated users in wso2am-2.1.0, but this issue appears in 2.1.0-uodate12 too. I thought I could just create a userstore for FEDERATED realm, but they the FEDERATED realm name is reserved :/